# Regex grouping confusion simple example

Tags: java, regex

New to regex in java =)

I want to see as output:

```
aaaa
 222212
adasas
```

what I really see is:

```
aaaa 222212 adasas
aaaa
 222212
```

Code tells more then text, so here is my code:

```
String sToPars = "aaaa 222212 adasas";

Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(^[A-Za-z]+)( [0-9]+)( [A-Za-z]+)");

Matcher matcher = p.matcher(sToPars);
matcher.find();

for(int i = 0; i < matcher.groupCount();i++){
    System.out.println(matcher.group(i));
}
```

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/groups.html What am I missing here..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the `matcher` object, the first group (index `0`) is the complete match.

Afterwards, `matcher`'s group of index `1` is the regex first capturing group's result, index `2` the second, etc...

To see what you want, you need to change your loop to:

```
for(int i = 1; i <= matcher.groupCount();i++)
```

Comment: you are right. But from docs "In the expression ((A)(B(C))), for example, there are four such groups".. then there should be actually 5 grups.. first the entire match,((A)(B(C))), and then the ((A)(B(C))) match then (A) then (B(C)) then (C)

Comment: See [groupcount doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#groupCount%28%29); the groupcount indeed returns the number of capturing groups. But your issue is on the `matcher.group` index: since the index `0` is occupied by something other than a capturing group you have to shift your loop index by one.

Answer (score 0):

group(0) will give you the whole string.

I have modified the for loop. Please check if this is works

```
    for(int i = 0; i <= matcher.groupCount();i++){
        System.out.println(matcher.group(i));
    }
```

basically group(3) was never getting queried by your for loop

Answer (score 0):

```
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("^([\\w ]+)$", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE | Pattern.UNICODE_CASE | Pattern.MULTILINE);
    Matcher regexMatcher = regex.matcher(subjectString);
    while (regexMatcher.find()) {
        for (int i = 1; i <= regexMatcher.groupCount(); i++) {
            // matched text: regexMatcher.group(i)
            // match start: regexMatcher.start(i)
            // match end: regexMatcher.end(i)
        }

/*
aaaa
 222212
adasas
*/
```